# Displaying Image with same sizes every alternate rows PHP

Tags: php

I am showing the images and getting all that images from database. I'm showing two images on one row, in which the first image is big in size while the second one is small in size. Now the 2nd row again have the two images but this time first image should be small and the second should be large.

I am using PHP and used 'foreach' for loop to get all the images form the database. So how can I do this ? here is a sample piece of code:

```
 <? foreach ($model->images as $img) { ?>
     <div class="big_img">
         <div class='list_img' style="background-image: url('<?= $img->url ? : UPLOAD_URL.'images/'.$img->image1?>')">
     </div>

     <div class="small_img">
         <div class='list_img' style="background-image: url('<?= $img->url ? : UPLOAD_URL.'images/'.$img->image2?>')">
     </div>
 <? } ?>
```

Comment: you need to use a modulus.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a variable and flip it each time:

```
<?
$cont = true;
foreach ($model->images as $img) { ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $cont ? 'big_img' : 'small_img'; ?>">
        <div class='list_img' style="background-image: url('<?= $img->url ? : UPLOAD_URL.'images/'.$img->image1?>')">
    </div>

    <div class="<?php echo !$cont ? 'small_img' : 'big_img'; ?>">
        <div class='list_img' style="background-image: url('<?= $img->url ? : UPLOAD_URL.'images/'.$img->image2?>')">
    </div>
<? $cont = !$cont; } ?>
```

So, basically, when the variable is `true`, display big-small and when it's `false`, small-big. Each iteration you negate the variable, meaning when it's `true`, it will become `false` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulo operator to determine what the order of the two sizes should be. Something along these lines (untested and very crude):

```
<? $index = 0; foreach ($model->images as $img) { ?>
     <div class="<? echo $index % 2 == 0 ? : 'big_img' : 'small_img'; ?>">
         <div class='list_img' style="background-image: url('<?= $img->url ? : UPLOAD_URL.'images/'.$img->image1?>')">
     </div>

     <div class="<? echo $index % 2 == 0 ? : 'small_img' : 'big_img'; ?>">
         <div class='list_img' style="background-image: url('<?= $img->url ? : UPLOAD_URL.'images/'.$img->image2?>')">
     </div>
 <? $index++; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

And just for the sake of it...

You can even (no pun intended) use [bitwise](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operations..

```
<?php

$index = 0;
foreach($things as $thing) {
    if( ++$index & 1 ) {
        // $index is odd
    } else {
        // $index is even
    }
}

?>
```